# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting following exception while calling a main method.
I am posting mapping file here. 
I think this is due to

```
 <list-index>
   <column name="bill_no" />
  </list-index>
```

What should be value for this

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="iland.hbm.BillDetails" table="bill_details" catalog="retail_shop">
        <id name="billNo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="bill_no" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="customerDetails" class="iland.hbm.CustomerDetails" fetch="join">
            <column name="customer_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="subTotal" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="sub_total" precision="10" />
        </property>

        <list name="billProductDetailses" table="bill_product_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <key>
                <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <list-index>
                <column name="bill_no" />
            </list-index>
            <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: iland.hbm.BillDetails.billProductDetailses column: bill_no
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at iland.database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:32)
    at iland.bill.BillDAO.fetchAll(BillDAO.java:94)
        Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: iland.hbm.BillDetails.billProductDetailses column: bill_no
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:354)
```

How to resolve above error.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are mapping twice the same column in your entity.

```xml
    <list name="billProductDetailses" table="bill_product_details" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key>
            <column name="bill_no" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <list-index>
            <column name="bill_no" />
        </list-index>
        <one-to-many class="iland.hbm.BillProductDetails" />
    </list>
```

When you map twice the same column (bill_product_details.bill_no) in an entity (suppose the properties A and B of your object reference the same column), Hibernate produces that exception because it doesn't know when to update/insert the datum on the db (when A is changed or when B is changed? And what if A and B are different?), so you have to tell it which one is the "master", let's say.

In addition, let me point out that I don't understand your mapping. The "key" should map to the column with the foreign key constraint, while the index should map the column indicating what will be the object's position in your list/array, so I really don't get why they both reference the same column. This way the position of the object in the array will be equal to the id of the referenced entry. Won't it?